# Multiply tensors containing matrices, following matrix multiplication rule

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Say I have a tensor, where `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are all 2x2 matrices:

```
M = [[A, B],
     [C, D]]
```

How do I get to the power of `n`, for example with `n=2`, with Python or MATLAB

```
M^2 = [[A@A + B@C, A@B + B@D],
       [C@A + D@C, C@B + D@D]]
```

Here the power just follows the normal matrix multiplication rule; it's just that the elements are matrices themselves. I tried `matmul`, `matrix_power`, and `pagemtimes`, but nothing works.

Comment: Have tried using NumPy's `asmatrix()` and `power()`?

Comment: For example, I tried
`a = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3];
b = reshape(a,2,2,2,2);
c = pagemtimes(b,b);
disp(c(:,:,1,1))`
giving the top left corner element of `c` being all zeros, which should be wrong, since it's `A@A + B@C`.

Comment: Tell us more about the shapes of A,B,C,D and M.  `np.matmul/@` can work with higher dimensions than 2 - read its docs.

Comment: I've edited the question. `A,B,C,D` are 2x2 matrices, and `M` is 2x2 matrices of 2x2 matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient, but here's a manual solution:

```
M = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 2, 2, 2))

def matmatmul(a, b):
    
    output = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1]), dtype = object)
    
    for i in range(output.shape[0]):
        for j in range(output.shape[1]):
            row = a[i]
            col = b[:, j]
            
            output[i,j] = sum([r @ c for r,c in zip(row, col)])
            
    return output

def matmatpow(a, n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    else:
        output = matmatmul(a, a)
        
        for i in range(2, n):
            output = matmatmul(output, a)
        
        return output
    
M2 = matmatpow(M, 2)

print(M2)

[[A, B], [C, D]] = M

assert np.all(M2[0,0] == A@A + B@C)
assert np.all(M2[0,1] == A@B + B@D)
assert np.all(M2[1,0] == C@A + D@C)
assert np.all(M2[1,1] == C@B + D@D)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are just computing the normal matrix product of the 4x4 block matrix created by joining the smaller matrices `A` through `D`.

In MATLAB, your expected  result using some arbitrary matrices:

```matlab
A = [1, 2
     3, 4];
B = [5, 6
     7, 8];
C = [ 9, 10
     11, 12];
D = [13, 14
     15, 16];

res = [A*A + B*C, A*B + B*D
       C*A + D*C, C*B + D*D]
```

```
res =
   118   132   174   188
   166   188   254   276
   310   356   494   540
   358   412   574   628
```

The 4x4 block matrix, and its square:

```matlab
M = [A, B
     C, D];
res2 = M^2
```

```
res2 =
   118   132   174   188
   166   188   254   276
   310   356   494   540
   358   412   574   628
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a set of (2,2) arrays, and their composite:

```
In [45]: A,B,C,D = [np.arange(i,i+4).reshape(2,2) for i in range(4)]    
In [46]: M=np.array([[A,B],[C,D]])
```

Your desired `M^2` array:

```
In [47]: np.array([[A@A + B@C, A@B + B@D],
    ...:       [C@A + D@C, C@B + D@D]])
Out[47]: 
array([[[[12, 16],
         [28, 40]],

        [[16, 20],
         [40, 52]]],


       [[[28, 40],
         [44, 64]],

        [[40, 52],
         [64, 84]]]])
```

The same thing using `einsum`.  In this `j` and `l` are the sum-of-products dimensions:

```
In [48]: np.einsum('ijkl,jmln->imkn',M,M)
Out[48]: 
array([[[[12, 16],
         [28, 40]],

        [[16, 20],
         [40, 52]]],


       [[[28, 40],
         [44, 64]],

        [[40, 52],
         [64, 84]]]])
```

`matmul` is the equivalent of  'ijkl,ijlm->ijkm', where `ij` are `batch` dimensions, and `l` is the sum-of-products.  Often an `einsum` can be reproduced with some reshape and generalized transposing.  But I'll leave that for someone else to explore.

Playing around with the einsum indices and transposing and reshaping the arrays, I can get the equivalent of:

```
In [56]: np.matmul(M.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4),M.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4))
Out[56]: 
array([[12, 16, 16, 20],
       [28, 40, 40, 52],
       [28, 40, 40, 52],
       [44, 64, 64, 84]])
```

which with a bit more massaging becomes the desired (4,4,4,4)

```
In [57]: np.matmul(M.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4),M.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)).reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[57]: 
array([[[[12, 16],
         [28, 40]],

        [[16, 20],
         [40, 52]]],


       [[[28, 40],
         [44, 64]],

        [[40, 52],
         [64, 84]]]])
```